# Can the same Opatch utility be used for patching both the database and grid?

Tags: oracle

Can the same Opatch utility present in the patch for database be used for patching a grid provided both the Grid and Database patches requires the same version of Opatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's advisable to always get the latest OPatch from [here](https://updates.oracle.com/download/6880880.html) (or follow metalink article 6880880).

Then just follow your patch notes for grid or database patches. It's the same OPatch software and it's always included in your RDBMS folder, but like I said, make sure you download the latest.